# To generate all combinations of a set of objects

Tags: java, object, combinations, powerset

I have a problem here where I need to generate all possible combinations of objects and store them in a list for analysis later on..

Searches on the Internet include many algorithms that fall short of this requirement of storing the combinations up. 
Most common searches generate the list of combinations simply by printing them out, while others are dealing with only strings of characters, rather than an object.

Some algorithm uses bits to represent the different combinations but this solution only limits to at most 32 objects, which is not good enough.

On the whole, I am looking for an algorithm where I can generate all possible combinations (power sets), deals with objects (more than 32), and not restricted to only printing out the combinations, but rather store these combinations in a list of arrays.

Comment: Do you have enough memory (and computing power) to generate and store the power set of a set that contains more than 32 elements? Such a power set would contain billions of elements...

Comment: To deal with that kind of datasets you need a full-blown mass-processing system set up. Forget about naïve single-JVM solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the idea of instead of generating all of the combinations at once into one potentially huge and unmanageable array you write a generator for each entry in the array, thus making a kind of pseudo array where accessing an entry creates the entry on the fly.

Here's the code of an `enum` iterator I posted in another question that gets close to that. Although it implements `Iterator`, internally it generates each combination by decoding its index and picking the combination from the bit pattern of the index on the fly (see the `private Enum[] get(int x)` method). It should be possible to extend it to use `BigInteger` or even a `byte[]` for the index if you like.

```
public class EnumIterator implements Iterator<Enum[]> {
  // The enum classes
  private final Class<? extends Enum>[] enums;
  // The pseudo-position in the list.
  private int i = 0;
  // The total entries in the list.
  private final int N;

  // Construct from classes.
  private EnumIterator(Class<? extends Enum>... enums) {
    // Grab the enums.
    this.enums = enums;
    // Work out the Max as the product of all sets of constants.
    int max = 1;
    for (int n = 0; n < enums.length; n++) {
      max *= enums[n].getEnumConstants().length;
    }
    N = max;
  }

  // Get that one from the possibles.
  private Enum[] get(int x) {
    // Make new array.
    Enum[] next = new Enum[enums.length];
    // Fill it with the ith entry.
    for (int j = next.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
      Enum[] e = enums[j].getEnumConstants();
      // Pick the right one from it.
      next[j] = e[x % e.length];
      // Fold out that enum.
      x /= e.length;
    }
    return next;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasNext() {
    return i < N;
  }

  @Override
  public Enum[] next() {
    if (hasNext()) {
      return get(i++);
    } else {
      throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void remove() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported.");
  }

  enum ABC {
    A, B, C;
  }

  enum XY {
    X, Y;
  }

  enum IJ {
    I, J;
  }

  enum OneTwoThree {
    ONE, TWO, THREE
  }

  private static void test() {
    // Also works - but constructing from classes is cleaner.
    //Iterator<Enum[]> i = new EnumIterator(ABC.values(), XY.values(), IJ.values());
    System.out.println("ABC x XY x IJ");
    for (Enum[] e : Iterables.in(new EnumIterator(ABC.class, XY.class, IJ.class))) {
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(e));
    }
    System.out.println("ABC");
    for (Enum[] e : Iterables.in(new EnumIterator(ABC.class))) {
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(e));
    }
    System.out.println("ABC x OneTwoThree");
    for (Enum[] e : Iterables.in(new EnumIterator(ABC.class, OneTwoThree.class))) {
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(e));
    }
    System.out.println("MT");
    for (Enum[] e : Iterables.in(new EnumIterator())) {
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(e));
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    test();
  }
}
```